# FCM onBackgroundMessage doesn't work on terminated state

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm implementing notifications in Android.

I want the notification to trigger a Dialog in app when pressed,
on the Foreground I had no problems showing it, I then used `FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp` for Background state and it worked as well.

Since both `FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp` and `FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage` were triggered when a notification was pressed in Background state I decided to not use `FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp` and stick with `FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage`.

I'm aware that `onBackgroundMessage` must be isolated and can't modify any UI logic, so I decided to call an API to check a flag "hasNotification" in my database.
Said so the method `onBackgroundMessage` gets triggered very few times in Background state and never gets triggered in Terminated state (both in my emulator and in my device) I don't know if I'm missing something.

I'm sending notifications through Firebase Messaging panel.

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import '../../../globals.dart' as globals;

import 'init.dart';
import 'package:gluten_free_demo/api/glt_insert_notification.dart';

Future<dynamic> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(
    RemoteMessage message) async {

  globals.notification['title'] = message.notification?.title;
  globals.notification['body'] = message.notification?.body;
  
  insertNotification(true);
  print("Handling background message, ${globals.notification}");
}

void main(List<String> args) async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  runApp(const Init());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive#apple_platforms_and_android) says the background message handler:

> 3. When using Flutter version 3.3.0 or higher, the message handler must be annotated with @pragma('vm:entry-point') right above the function declaration (otherwise it may be removed during tree shaking for release mode).

I am guessing that you using Flutter version 3.3.0 or higher, So you have to add `@pragma('vm:entry-point')` at the top of handler.

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<dynamic> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(
    RemoteMessage message) async {

  globals.notification['title'] = message.notification?.title;
  globals.notification['body'] = message.notification?.body;
  
  insertNotification(true);
  print("Handling background message, ${globals.notification}");
}
```